# Square root of a $3\times3$ matrix

Tags: matrices

Here is  $3\times3$ matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}   0&    0&    1\\
    0  & -1 &   0\\
    1&    0  &  0\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I solve this  by using Cayley-Hamilton?
I know how to use Cayley-Hamilton for a $2$-dimensional matrix.
How can it help in finding the square root of a $3\times3$ matrix?
for 2 dimensional matrix we can solve this equation `A^2−(trA)A+(detA)I=0` 
we have A and I,
we can compute `det(A^2)` so we have det A,
and  we can find A.

for 2 dimensional matrix using above equation we can compute square root.
for example we have this matrix:

A^2= $$\begin{pmatrix}   4&    2\\
        2&    2\end{pmatrix}$$

```
det A^2= 4

det A=2




4 2             1 0
2 2  +6 *A+ 2*  0 1 =0
```

by solving above equation we can find A.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the characteristic equation? Give us the progress you've had this far.

Comment: what is characteristic equation?

Comment: Your matrix has a negative eigenvalue, so it will not have a positive square root. Are you sure that is what you want to find? How would you find the square root of a $2\times 2$ matrix from the equation you put in the question?

Comment: If the matrix is not positive definite, it does not have a square root over $\Bbb{R}$...

Comment: I don't see how your approach helps to get the square $S$ of a matrix $M$, such that $S^2=M$...

Comment: i edit question and add example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your matrix $M$ is symmetric you can diagonalize it. You'll get $M=U \cdot D \cdot U^\dagger$, where $D$ contains the eigenvalues and $U$ contains the eigenvectors. Take the square roots of the eigenvalues  to get $D_{\sqrt \cdot}$ and transform the resulting diagonal matrix $U^\dagger \cdot D_{\sqrt{.}}\cdot U=S$. It's obvious to see that $S^2=M$.

**EDIT**

And even that I don't understand your original approach, you can use it when you rewrite your matrix to 
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\1&0&0\\0&0&-1}.
$$
Now you have one $2\times 2$ block suitable for your approach.

Comment: how can i rewrite matrix to that one?

Comment: @saeedeh you conjugate $M$ with a matrix $P$ representing the permutation of indices. $PMP^{-1}$ should be the rewritten matrix...

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by Euler's method of solving for the (later named) unit-length eigenvector (a tilted 3D rotational axis), and the Euler 2D angle theta of rotation about the 3D Euler axis.

I did it computationally.

The square root matrix is:
{ { 0.5  , 0.7071, 0.5 }, {-0.7071,0,0.7071}, {0.5,-.7071,0.5}}